# Finding for keys with multiple values in a nested python dictonary

Tags: python

I am trying to index through a nested dictionary as given below and trying to find the key value which has a value -i.e a dictionary that has keys with multiple values. When I index through A, I would need the keys 1 and 2 as a result. Is there an efficient way to perform this operation on a huge dictionary (outermost) with many keys.

example below :

```
A = { 0:{0:[1], 1:[2]}, 1:{0:[2],2:[3,4]}, 2:{3:[4],7:[4,7]}, 3:{4:[45]} }
```

Appreciate any pointers regarding this. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: A = { 0:{0:[1], 1:[2]}, 1:{0:[2],2:[3,4]}, 2:{3:[4],7:[4,7]}, 3:{4:[45]} }

In [2]: [ k for (k,v) in A.items()
            if any(len(subv) > 1 for subv in v.values())]
Out[2]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.ifilter` and a generator expression.

```
import itertools
results = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x != None,(v if any(len(A[v][vk]) > 1 for vk in A[v]) else None for v in A))
print list(results)

[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
A = { 0:{0:[1], 1:[2]}, 1:{0:[2],2:[3,4]}, 2:{3:[4],7:[4,7]}, 3:{4:[45]} }

def print_dict(values_index): 
    for value in A[values_index]:
        print A[values_index][value]

print_dict(0) #You can change 0 with any other key to find the values
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1]
[2]
```

If you need them into a list instead of `print` use `list_name.append(...)`

NOTE: I wrote the code to make it as readable as possible even by less experienced people, but I still think it's one of the best ways if you are working with just int values and each key differences with previous one by 1

Answer (score 0):

```
A = { 0:{0:[1], 1:[2]}, 1:{0:[2],2:[3,4]}, 2:{3:[4],7:[4,7]}, 3:{4:[45]} }
[k for (k,v) in filter(lambda kv: len(filter(lambda kv2: len(kv2[1])>1, kv[1].iteritems()))>0, A.iteritems())]
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2]
```